# four-point forward-difference formula using Newton's form for first order derivative

Tags: approximation, derivative

We know that ${f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{h}}$. If we have three points ${x_0 = x-h}$, ${x_1 = x}$, ${x_2 = x + h}$, we can compute the 3-point centered-difference formula using the Newton's form:
${g(x) = f_0 + (x-x_0)\cdot f[x_0,x_1] + (x-x_0)\cdot(x-x_1)\cdot f[x_0,x_1,x_2]}$

We then have:
${g'(x) = f[x_0,x_1] + [(x-x_0) + (x-x_1)]\cdot f[x_0,x_1,x_2]}$

If we differentiate for $x_1$:
${g'(x_1) = f[x_0,x_1] + (x-x_0)\cdot f[x_0,x_1,x_2]} \approx f'(x) $

By divided differences we get
${f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}}$

Because:
${g'(x) = \frac{f_1-f_0}{x_1-x_0} + (x_1-x_0)\cdot \frac{\frac{f_2-f_1}{x_2-x_1} - \frac{f_1-f_0}{x_1-x_0}}{x_2-x_0}}$

${= \frac{2f_1 - 2f_0}{2h} +h\cdot \frac{\frac{f_2-f_1}{h} - \frac{f_1-f_0}{h}}{2h}}$

${= \frac{f_2-f_0}{2h}}$

Where ${f_2 = f(x+h)}$ and ${f_0 = f(x-h)}$
Now what I have to find is the 4-point forward-difference formula (I cannot use the centered one because my points are ${x_0 = x}$, ${x_1 = x+h}$, ${x_2 = x + 2h}$, ${x_3 = x+3h}$), and from here, get the third order method for approximating the first derivative. What I had so far is to compute the Newton form for 4 points:
${g(x) = f_0 + (x-x_0)\cdot f[x_0,x_1] + (x-x_0)\cdot(x-x_1)\cdot f[x_0,x_1,x_2] + (x-x_0)\cdot(x-x_1)\cdot(x-x_2)\cdot f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]}$

Then I took the derivative:
${g'(x) = f[x_0,x_1] + [(x-x_0) + (x-x_1)]\cdot f[x_0,x_1,x_2] + (3x^2 -2xx_2 -2xx_1 + x_2x_1 - 2xx_0 +x_2x_0 + x_1x_0)\cdot f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]}$

My problem is that I don't know how to reorder ${(3x^2 -2xx_2 -2xx_1 + x_2x_1 - 2xx_0 +x_2x_0 + x_1x_0)}$ such that I get a form similar to ${(x-x_0) + (x-x_1)}$ (differences), because if I have that order, I can then substitute the differences between the points with their distance, e.g. ${h}$, to get the clean solution for ${f'(x)}$.

Comment: This would be a better fit for math.SE because it has no statistical content. I tried to migrate it for you, except that failed because you're banned from asking questions there. Persisting in asking off-topic questions will eventually have you banned from asking questions here, as well.